# form.serializeArray() converts each element into string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to form.serializeArray() and passing serialized data to the server.

Problem: This method also converts boolean and integer to string. And on server side on the basis of the
         value , I am trying to get the data type because of which it gives me String everytime.

Actual Output:
 `[Object { name="para1", value="1"}, Object { name="para2", value="2"}, Object { name="para3", value="true"}, Object { name="para4", value="rep1"}]`

Required Output:

```
[Object { name="para1", value=1}, Object { name="para2", value=2}, Object { name="para3", value=true}, Object { name="para4", value="rep1"}]
```

Please suggest the solution for this.

Comment: Thanks for your precious time @Vohuman, i am using textbox for entering the values. so please can you suggest me to get required output

Comment: Form elements cannot store boolean values. As @Vohuman wrote, all values in form elements are strings. But you can use numeric string  values (`0`, `1`) with `select` elements to substitute boolean values

Comment: @PrashantMirchandani `i am using textbox for entering the values` so how can you expect it to be anything else but string?

Comment: @A.Wolff , so what can be alternative?

Comment: Cannot you provide relevant HTML markup in question too and jsFiddle? I'm really not sure to understand your issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could process the `value` string of each object and create a new array with converted values. For example, the strings `true` and `false` would be converted to their respective boolean value and numbers would be converted to integers. Note that my example below is quite simple and doesn't cover all possibilities (floats are also converted to integers).

**Edit:** As noted by @sanfor in the comments, every string containing an integer is converted to an integer value, although strings like `"123"` could also be treated as strings. However, given the information in the question that the type of the input is unknown, this method provides the desired results.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8fwafnr/2/) (open the console to see the output):

```
var values = [
    {
        name: 'para1',
        value: '1'
    },
    {
        name: 'para2',
        value: 'true'
    },
    {
        name: 'para3',
        value: 'this is a string'
    }
];

var result = values.map(function(obj) {
    var value;

    if (obj.value === 'true') {
        value = true;
    } else if (obj.value === 'false') {
        value = false;
    } else if (!isNaN(obj.value)) {
        value = parseInt(obj.value);
    } else {
        value = obj.value;
    }

    return {
        name: obj.name,
        value: value
    };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You are missing the fact that string can also contain numbers. That is why you can't just post-process it like this.

Comment: As I said, the example doesn't cover all possibilities. But it's stated in the question that the type of the input text is not known beforehand. Therefore, you have to make the assumption that a string that contains a valid integer is supposed to be treated as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

As @Vohuman already mentioned, the values are strings as intended. To make them something else you would need to either use some other function to achieve it, or handle the output of the *serializeArray* afterwards.

More likely solution is to teach your back-end to resolve the type based on the field. You usually know what you are expecting on back-end so you also know the type required and based on that you can (try) to cast it to be correct type.

Comment: Thanks @sanfor, the datatypes of values of the elements are not fixed because of which it can contain integer,string or boolean. i am trying at backed to get its datatype by value.getClass().getName() in java and because of this it everytime give me string

Comment: @PrashantMirchandani: As I mentioned already, you can also handle the output of _serializeArray_ some way. For example you could add a third parameter for each _Object_ such as type: "Integer" based on what the value was before the serialization. The type is most easily fetched with `typeof obj`. Type strings gotten from that are in your case "string", "number" or "boolean".

Comment: i have used typeof but it returns me string only

Comment: Yes, of course it does after you have called the _serializeArray_ and try to do it for value. But if your values are initially of type boolean or number, typeof will return "boolean" or "number".